# How to Convert Column Field into Hyperlink with xslt

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-enterprise, xslt

Salvete!  In my list, I have a column formatted as a Number, titled, say, "My Number", and the actual markup name of the column is "My_Number".

Now, I want to convert the entire column, in any list, into a hyperlink, so that the link becomes something like "My Number"

I have read [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40930/how-to-attach-programmatically-and-xsl-to-a-view) and [here](https://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/sharepoint-2010-list-column-that-renders-as-a-dynamic-hyperlink/), and [Microsoft's page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx), too, that this might be accomplished with xslt, but even after an iis reset, I can't seem to change the field values into the links that I want.  Here is my custom `fldtypes_MyNumber.xsl`, which is placed in the `/_layouts/XSL` directory:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
version="1.0" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" 
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" 
xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='My_Number']" >
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <a target="_blank" href="/mypages/mysite{$thisNode/@My_Number}">{$thisNode/@My_Number}</a>
</xsl:template>
```

So what do I do to get this to work?

**[UPDATE]**

I changed `mode=Number` to `mode=Number_body` and now the hyperlink is generated and inserted properly!  However, the hyperlink text label is rendered literally...  How do I use the text that was originally there as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! It was a matter of manipulating xsl markup in the right fashion.  Here is the final result.  It transforms an ordinary number in a Number column into a hyperlink.

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='My_Number']" mode="Number_body">
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <a target="_blank">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">/mypages/mysite<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@My_Number"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@My_Number" />
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```